# Debugging header files in codeblocks

Tags: c, header, codeblocks

I am trying to debug header file in codeblocks. I have tried some options like "run to cursor" and by putting breakpoint in header file but it doesn't stops there and passes through there.
How can I debug .h file in it?
If you need any information, just comment. I'll provide the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugger executes your program, after it has been compiled (and the compiler has been
instructed to insert *debugging information* into compiled program). It lets you pause the 
execution at breakpoints you have set in the code, but it can only pause at a breakpoint if 
you have set the breakpoint *at some line of executable code that the program reaches at some point when it runs.* 
If you set a breakpoint at some line that isn't executable code, or at some line that *is* executable 
but the program never reaches, then the debugger will never reach that breakpoint.

Look at this toy C program and consider each of the places *A*,...,*I* where you might set a
breakpoint in Code::Blocks:

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#define FORTY_TWO 42  /* A */
extern void the_answer_is(void); /*B*/

#endif
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foo.h" /* C */
#include <stdio.h>

static int forty_two = FORTY_TWO; /* D */

void the_answer_is(void) /* E */
{
    int i = forty_two; /* F */
    printf("The answer is...%d\n",i); /* G */
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void) /* H */
{
    the_answer_is(); /* I */
    return 0;
}
```

**Breakpoint at A?**

This is a preprocessor directive. The preprocessor removes it from the source 
code before it gets to the compiler. So the compiler never sees it. So the
debugger knows nothing about it. There is no executable code here. A breakpoint
will never be reached.

**Breakpoint at B?**

This is an external function declaration. It provides necessary information to the
compiler and the linker. But it's not executable code.
`extern void the_answer_is(void);` is not something your program can *do*. 
This breakpoint will never be reached.

**Breakpoint at C?**

The story here is the same as *A*, except that the preprocessor removes the
`#include` directive and replaces it with the (preprocessed) contents of
`foo.h`. This breakpoint will never be reached.

**Breakpoint at D?**

This line is a global static initialization. It's done at compiletime,
before your program ever runs. No executable code. This breakpoint will never be reached.

**Breakpoint at E?**

This line is a function entry point, beginning a function definition.
It is not *itself* executable code, but it is the entry point of some
executable code. So a breakpoint here can be reached. The debugger will
just "overshoot" a little and stop at the first executable line in the
function definition.  Your program will get to a breakpoint here *if* the function, `the_answer_is` 
gets called at some point in execution.

**Breakpoint at F?**

This line defines and initializes `int i`. A breakpoint here will be
reached in the same circumstances as *E*, and it is where the debugger
would actually stop for a breakpoint at *E*.

**Breakpoint at G?**

The most interesting one. This line is a call to a function that is
defined in an external library (the Standard C Library). The compiler will have seen the
`extern` declaration of `printf` when it read the header `<stdio.h>`
If you had opened up `stdio.h` and put a breakpoint at the `extern`
declaration of `printf`, it would never be reached (same as *B*). But
here we have a *call* to `printf`, and that call be reached in the
same circumstances as *E* and *F*.

So this breakpoint can be reached. But suppose you reach it and you
then want to *step into* this call to `printf` in the debugger. You
won't be able to. The debugger will just step over it. *Your program*
has been compiled with debugging information, but the library in which
`printf` is defined has not. You don't compile that library at all; you just
link it with your program. Without debugging information about the library,
and access to its source code, the debugger can't step into it; so it
doesn't.

You might be under the impression that if you *could* "step into"
a header like `<stdio.h>` you would find the source code of the
library functions that are declared there, say `printf`, and you could
debug into it. You wouldn't find the source code there. All you would find is
the external declaration:

```
extern int printf( const char* format, ... );
```

The role of `<stdio.h>` for your compiler is just to inform it what the names
of the `stdio` library functions are and how they should be called. Then
it can tell you if you call a function that hasn't been declared or call it
in the wrong way. It doesn't need the source code of `printf` because its already compiled in the
Standard C Library, which your program is automatically linked with.

**Breakpoint at H?**

This is the entry point of your whole program, so this breakpoint
will *always* be reached, barring catastrophic accidents. Just as for
*E*, the debugger will stop at the next executable line.

**Breakpoint at I?**

This call to `the_answer_is` will always be reached, just like *H*.
And because we now know that `the_answer_is` gets called, we also know
that the breakpoints *E*,*F* and *G* *will* be reached.

**Bottom line**:

- It is pointless to put breakpoints at `#include` directives
  or any other preprocessor directives. The compiler never sees them;
  the debugger knows nothing about them.
- In general, in C, it is pointless to put breakpoints *within* header
  files, because they just contain declarations and preprocessor
  directives, not executable code. (In C++, it is quite a different story.
  C++ headers usually contain executable code, and you can place breakpoints
  in them.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I really like how you broke down the lines with letters. This is a great example for the quality of stackoverflow.